# C# Xpath can't get element by name

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Have document loaded to XmlDocument with next srtucture

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FictionBook xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0" xmlns:l="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <stylesheet type="text/css"></stylesheet>
  <description>...</description>
  <body>...</body>
  <binary id="19317.jpg" content-type="image/jpeg">...</binary>
</FictionBook>
```

Next metods return me null (or empty collection if i use SelectNodes):

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("body");
doc.SelectSingleNode("//body");
doc.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("body");
doc.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

But this one works correctly

```
doc.LastChild["body"];
```

Why XPath don't give me any results?

Answer (score 1):

`doc.SelectSingleNode("//body");` doesn't work because `body` is declared in a specific namespace "http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0", so to query for it you could code it like this:

```
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
mgr.AddNamespace("whatever", "http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0");
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//whatever:body", mgr);
```

`doc.LastChild["body"]`; works because the implementation supports it, but you could use it like this to avoid ambiguities:

```
doc.LastChild["body", "http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"]
```